# How can i know what the custom soundcloud player is playing?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm working with the custom soundcloud player to build a website around my own tracks.

The point is that i want the website to show for every track a different background image. 
The player has several events, but they do not provide me the track id or track title of the currently playing track. How can i know what the player is playing?

thanks!

Comment: Can you give as a link to the player's code and api documentation?

Comment: i am using the sc-player-red version and i do not have yet any own code, because i first need to know if the custom player fits my needs. It seems it does: i found out the following:  
(document).bind('soundcloud:onPlayerReady', function(event, data) {
player = soundcloud.getPlayer('scPlayerEngine');
track = player.api_getCurrentTrack();
console.log(track);`code`

Comment: sory for my messy reply, but the main thing is: i found out how to do it. Thanks Bergi!

Answer (score 0):

In the [wiki (events section)](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/wiki#wiki-events) we can find the `onPlayerTrackSwitch.scPlayer` event, which fires every time the scPlayer changes track. The event has a track object as an argument which you can use to identify the currently playing track.

```
$(document).bind('onPlayerTrackSwitch.scPlayer', function(event, track){
  console.log(event.target, 'it jumped to this track:', track);
});
```